# Application Craft and QR Code reader

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, android-widget

I am working on a mobile application (Android)using application craft which is a web-based technology which can also be ported to an android app. I would like to know how is it possible to allow my system to activate the camera device in the mobile device so that the user is able to capture the QR code and the system is able to decode and display the details accordingly.

I am not intending to use the QR technology to navigate users to a link but use the technology to display details.

Hope someone can enlighten me.

Comment: do u want to use phonegap for using camera?

Comment: Yes i want to use phonegap as application craft is connected to phone gap

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BarcodeScanner